# Can arbitrary byte arrays be constructed pre-compile time from various structs using macros in C?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, literals

We all know that we can "mash" together string literals in C without most compilers troubling us, for example `char[] result = "a" "b"; // result = "ab"`. I want to generalize this idea to structs.

Suppose I have the following structs:

```
typedef struct s1 {
 char a;
 int b;
} s1_t;

typedef struct s2 {
 int c;
} s2_t;
```

Effectively I want to declare byte arrays that are arbitrary combinations of `s1_t` and `s2_t`. Is this reasonably possible? I would prefer not to use unions. The contents of the structs will be known at compile time.

Comment: May I ask the reason for not using unions? It seems to me like a perfect case for using them.

Comment: Honestly, if you are just serializing to an array, memcpy it where you want and call it good.  More so because your sizes are different and won't memory align well at all.

Comment: How would you type `s1_t` or `s2_2` literals in your source?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Embedded system programming, every byte counts!
@MichaelDorgan `memcpy` requires I know ahead of time the number of bytes I will be requesting, or that I can easily calculate it, which is not true in my case.
@ysap we can assume C99 and use compound literals (`(s1_t){'a', 10}`) or whatever works, really.

Comment: If you can't define a predictable, consistent structure for your data, then how do you anticipate *consuming* it?

Comment: Good question, but that has already been handled. Perhaps a little more context is what is required. We are working with a postfix expression evaluator that represents expressions as sequential bytecode (which is just serialized structs) that is part of a data-processing tool. We are trying to provide a reasonable way for our future users to write these expressions as efficiently as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We all know that we can "mash" together string literals in C without most compilers troubling us

Indeed, no conforming C compiler will complain, as the semantics of such constructs are defined explicitly by the standard(s).  I mention this to highlight that the result is not accidental, subject to luck or compiler whim, or any such thing, as your comments seem to allow as possibilities.

> Effectively I want to declare byte arrays that are arbitrary combinations of [two structure types]. Is this reasonably possible? I would prefer not to use unions.

Strictly speaking, it is not possible.  You cannot use `struct` literals in any combination to initialize a byte array.  You can achieve something fairly close in C99 or later using unions, and if you want compile-time initialization from `struct` literals, then I don't see any other option.  It would look like this:

```
typedef union {
    s1_t s1;
    s2_t s2;
} s_u;

s_u array[] = {
    { .s1 = (s1_t) { 'a', 42 } },
    { .s1 = (s1_t) { 'b', 17 } },
    { .s2 = (s2_t) { 1856 } },
    { .s1 = (s1_t) { 'Q', -1 } }
};

unsigned char *byte_array = (unsigned char *)array;
```

I suppose, however, that your reason for wanting to avoid unions is to pack together `struct` representations of different sizes without padding.  This is not possible.  Indeed, even with only **one** struct type, it is not necessarily possible to arrange instances without any padding between last element of one instance and the first of the next instance.  It may not be easy even to force it with `memcpy()`, as the representations of your `struct`s can have both trailing padding and internal padding, all accounted in their sizes.  And don't forget that the values of any padding bytes are undefined.

You describe the result you're after as "sequential bytecode" and "*serialized* structs" (emphasis added).  I can't be certain what "serialized" means to you in this context, but to me it normally means something quite different from "internal representation".  In fact, avoiding dependency on internal representation is one of the main reasons for serialization.

If your objective conforms to my idea of serialization, then your best bet for avoiding making your users write bytecode is to provide them a bytecode compiler, with input and output in whatever forms will be most convenient.

Comment: +1, but it worth mentioning that some compilers let you enforce a "packed" memory organization on your structures, thus eliminating padding. GCC, for one, has the attribute `packed` to identify that.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to achieve something like what you're after with some nasty macro-based clunkery, if your data structure is defined in a separate file which code can `#include`ed multiple times while different macros are in effect.

Suppose for example that your data is in a file `foo.dat` of the following format:

```
INTS(1,2)
IDBL(-4,3)
INTS(5,23)
```

Items should be listed on separate lines, with *no semicolons*.

One could start by doing something like:

```
#define INTS(x,y) INT_PAIR Field ## __LINE__;
#define IDBL(x,y) INT_DBL  Field ## __LINE__;
struct ALL_DATA {
#include "foo.dat"
  int END_OF_DATA;
};
#undef INTS
#undef INTS
```

This would then be followed by:

```
#define INTS(x,y) {(x),(y)},
#define IDBL(x,y) {(x),(y)},
const struct ALL_DATA all_data = {
#include "foo.dat"
  0};
#undef INTS
#undef INTS
```

At that point one would have a compile-time constant structure containing a concatenation of a mixture of the other structure types, which could be parsed at run-time if it was constructed according to some form of known rules (e.g. the first value is positive for all int/int pairs, negative for all int/double pairs, and zero for end-of-data).

If one wanted to have an array containing the starting offsets of all the items (in int-sized units) from the start of the structure, one could use a couple more inclusions:

```
#define INTS(x,y) INT_PAIR FIELD_ID_ ## __LINE__, dummy1x ## __LINE__,
#define IDBL(x,y) INT_DBL  FIELD_ID_ ## __LINE__, \
    dummy1x ## __LINE__, dummy2x ## __LINE__,
enum DATA_IDS {
#include "foo.dat"
  dummy_end_id};
#undef INTS
#undef INTS
#define INTS(x,y) FIELD_ID_ ## __LINE__, 
#define IDBL(x,y) FIELD_ID_ ## __LINE__,
unsigned int data_offsets[] = {
#include "foo.dat"
  -1};
#undef INTS
#undef INTS
```

I don't know any way to make this work without either abusing the `__LINE__` directive or requiring that each line of the data file supply a unique identifier name; which approach is preferable could be open to discussion.